# TFS and VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I attempted to open a solution today at my new job and it said I need to convert it because it was made in an earlier version of Visual Studio. It also said that the solution would automatically be checked out in source control.

Obviously I do not want to do anything that messes anything up. Is it possible to just change my target framework in Visual Studio and not have to deal with any conversion stuff, or should I just install Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: we don't know! What is your in-house standard? 2008 or 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ANY developers are still using VS 2008, do not upgrade the solution. You can create a new solution and have it sit "side by side" or you can branch the code. But if you overwrite the solution with a VS 2010 solution, they will not be able to work on it again.

Comment: No, not strictly, but the solution file for VS 2010 is destructive in the general sense, and I would not head that direction. Now, there are some clever ways to set the solution up so you have a VS2010 and VS2008 solution side by side.

Comment: One more thing. The bigger issue with VS2010 is when you use the new coding constructs, many of which will still compile back to 2.x (including 3.x). You end up with major code breakage this way and it is not easy to fix. Worst thing is the developer often does not realize he is hosing someone else. Best option is edit the old code in VS2008 until everyone upgrades. It is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

It will break compatibility with Visual Studio 2008. Keep your company's solutions the same format as you get them unless directed to change them.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your target framework, but that will not stop the conversion.  The issue is with the project and solution files.  The are XML based MSBUILD.  What is happening is an upgrade of MSBUILD, not the .NET framework.

You should install VS2008 and use it until all possible team members are upgraded to VS2010. Once you upgrade, members using VS2008 will not be able to open the solution. There are some was to hack around MSBUILD upgrades, but I don't recommend them.